# iptables forwarding port to internal IP

Tags: iptables, vps, openvpn, port, forwarding

I'm using OpenVPN on a VPS which I want to forward incoming port 7999 from the external IP 198.23.248.150 to the internal IP 10.1.10.2 using iptables. I cannot seem to get the syntax correct and I have made sure forwarding is enabled:

```
root@insanity:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/venet0/forwarding             
1
```

So if anyone could tell me the iptables command I'm looking to use I'd appreciate it so much. I'm losing my mind trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 198.23.248.150 -p tcp --dport 7999 -j DNAT -to-destination 10.1.10.2`

and

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Also make sure that you've enabled forwarding persistent across reboots.

`# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

And don't forget to check routing on VPS and on the remote box which has internal IP.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean check routing on VPS and on remote box which has internal IP. But after doing the commands you said, I can telnet to 10.1.10.2 port 7999 and get an established connection, but I cannot telnet to 198.23.248.150 port 7999 and get a connection.

Comment: How can you connect to internal IP from Internet??

Comment: It doesn't work: root@insanity:~# telnet 10.1.10.2 7987 Trying 10.1.10.2... Connected to 10.1.10.2. Escape character is '^]'. root@insanity:~# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 198.23.248.150 \ -p tcp --dport 7987 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.10.2 root@insanity:~# telnet 198.23.248.150 7987 Trying 198.23.248.150... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: To have connections to the external IP from the machine itself work the DNAT rules also needs to be in the OUTPUT chain.